# Emails sent from outlook don't bear my name

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

When I send emails from outlook using an account such as `jd@companyname.com`, the recipient only sees `jd` mentioned as the sender instead of the full name `John Doe` in his inbox. How does one change settings in Outlook so that the emails bear your full name as the sender in the recipient's inbox?

FWIW, I use Outlook to work with my emails from a squirrelmail account.

Comment: Look in `Outlook Options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **FILE > Info > Account Settings**. Select your account in the list and click the **Change...** button. Fill **Your Name** as needed and click Next and OK.